# How partitions work in spark streaming and the co-relation between spark executors and partitions

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming job, receiving input form Kafka and wants to know how Spark partitions in spark streaming works ,how they are related to spark executors , are the number of Spark partitions is kept same as of Kafka partition if we don't do specify explicitly

Comment: Is it the Kafka partitions or the Spark partitions? Can you clarify?

Comment: Spark partitions

Comment: What's the Spark version and Kafka? What's the dependency on the Kafka module for Spark Streaming?

Comment: Spark 1.6 and Kafka 0.8

Comment: Hi how do you create your Kafka stream? Could you add that part of your code?

Comment: Using createDirectStream for receiving kafka stream : 
           
         val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic))